# Messages / Inbox API for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is there an API in the Windows Phone 8 SDK that lets me get a count of the unread emails or text messages on the phone? I don't want to read the contents (yet), I just want to know how many there are.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible sorry.

Here is an example on most of the personal things you can read about the user:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIbrary/microsoft.phone.userdata(v=vs.92)

Comment: dead link unfortunately.